# How to wire a custom MailProducer with jBPM 4.3?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I have a custom mail producer implementation that creates Multipart MimeMessages with "alternative" contentType.

But how can I wire my implementation instead of the default one ? (org.jbpm.pvm.internal.email.impl.MailProducerImpl)